# Converting Pandas Dateframe of one type to another

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Current type:
[image]
The above has the above dtype with index values

Desired type:
[image]

The below one don't have the index values. I want to convert from the above type to the below type.

Comment: `df = df.set_index('Date')`?

Comment: Hi Henry, yes, it works temporarily. If once again I try to use df, it is back to the previous type. I have to create another variable, say new_df = df.set_index('Date'), but I cannot modify df.

Comment: I don't understand. Providing your code would be helpful if you would like assistance in debugging it.

Comment: Okay, what I am saying is the following. When I invoke set_index('Date') on the df, and print the df immediately below, the df has the new format. But, somewhere down the line, when I print df, it is back to the old format, and I have to keep invoking set_index('Date') every time i use it in different places. That is the issue. Hope you get the problem. Currently, I am using a new variable, say, new_df = df.set_index('Date') to overcome the situation. I am trying to see if I can avoid this new variable. Hope you get this picture.

Comment: `set_index` returns a new data frame so you must assign it to a variable: `df = df.set_index('Date')`. An alternative is to modify it in-place: `df.set_index(inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

This way you can permanently modify the data frame and change the order of columns accordingly.

```
df = df.set_index("date")[<List of column names with your desired order>]
```